# Action bar back button not working in webview

Tags: android, webview

In my android webView the back button present in the android action bar is not working whereas the hardware button works perfectly, I even have a menu button present in the action bar that works too.

**Java file**

```
    public class online extends AppCompatActivity{

    private WebView webView;
    private ImageButton btn_webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_online);

        String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686; en-US; rv:1.9.0.4) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0";

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(userAgent);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/");

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(webView.canGoBack()){
            webView.goBack();
        }else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if(id == R.id.btn_home)
        {
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this Use **`android.R.id.home`**

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Back Button clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            this.finish();
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use below code.

```
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if(id == R.id.btn_home)
    {
       onBackPressed();
    }
    return true;
}
```